# Unable to install `vue-devtools`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

Создал проект [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue). Выполняю `yarn run dev` и получаю в консоли:

```
Unable to install `vue-devtools`:
   Error: Exited with code 2
      at ChildProcess.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/cross-unzip/index.js?:38:21)
      at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

Приложение правда запускается, но все равно хотелось бы это исправить.

P.S. Windows 10

Comment: разобрались с этим вопросом?

Comment: @Дмытрык нет, актуально!